# Induction pitfalls with O notation and recursion

Tags: asymptotics, induction, big-o-notation

I read the following in [CLRS 3rd Ed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844):

[image]

I'm not sure I understand exactly how to avoid this pitfall.

1. How would one know that the $\mathcal{O}$ notation in this case grows with $n$ and is thus not constant?
2. What's a good way to systematically avoid this type of pitfall?

Comment: There is no good answer for this. The notation is ambiguous. When proving $f(n) = O(n)$ by induction, it's best to instead prove $f(n) \leq Cn$, which would avoid such problems.

Comment: What you can say is that you have $n$ terms, each $O(n)$, thus the sum is $O(n^2)$.